# Bronze backsplash behind stove

Tags: backsplash

I see stainless steel being used more and more behind the stove as a backsplash. Stainless steel sheets are pretty easy to find. I prefer the look of red patinated bronze but cannot source bronze sheets locally (Ottawa, Canada).  I think brass is a bit too bright and shiny, but am finding that difficult to source as well.

Has anyone ever used bronze sheets in a backsplash?  What guage did you use - was it easy to cut and bend if required? And most importantly, where did you the source material?

Comment: « Let your fingers do the walking » try the local phone book - now usually online.

Comment: Type a search using your favorite search engine for something like "bronze sheet".  I tried this and found numerous local and online suppliers.

Comment: [Edit] to remove the "And most importantly..." part of the question, which everyone seems to be focused on, and you've got a perfectly good question. Unfortunately, "shopping" or "resource location" questions are explicitly off-topic because answers will only be good for people in Ottawa, and likely only until the end of the week because companies come and go it an internet minute.

Answer (score 2):

Just get a stainless steel sheet and run over it with a propane torch.  It will oxidize the steel and you can get a variety of colors.  Lighter temps give yellows, golds, bronze going to purple and blue as the heat is higher.

Once you get what you want you will need to put Urethane or something tough over it because the oxide layer is thin and can scratch off.  If you make a mistake you can steel wool it off and try again.

Comment: Neat idea. This is something more on the artistic side that I had not even been aware of.  I may just try this if the bronze doesn't pan out.